# How can I use launch4j to wrap a GUI application that also provides a command line interface?

Tags: java, shell, maven, launch4j

I am developing a Java application, which is mainly a GUI application. However, it also provides a command line interface. I can divide the command line parameters in three different types:

- The first type of parameter changes the behavior of the GUI.
- The second type starts the GUI in a specific state.
- The third type causes the application to directly execute an action without displaying the GUI.

When I execute the application with `java -jar <application-name>.jar -parameter`, everything works as expected. The application executes what it is asked to do. After the application is closed or finished, the shell prompt returns.

**Problem**

When I use launch4j to create a windows wrapper from the jar file, this behavior changes. The shell prompt always returns immediately. Thus, I can still pass command line parameters, but I cannot interact with the application via the terminal. It does not print anything that is written to stdout or stderr and it also cannot read anything from stdin.

**Question**

How can I configure launch4j to create an exe wrapper that provides the same command line behavior as the wrapped jar file?

**Additional Information**

I use the launch4j maven plugin with the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>launch4j</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>launch4j</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <headerType>gui</headerType>
                <stayAlive>true</stayAlive>
                <outfile>path/to/outfile.exe</outfile>
                <jar>path/to/infile.jar</jar>
                <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
                <errTitle>Error in Launcher</errTitle>
                <classPath>
                    <mainClass>com.example.Launch</mainClass>
                    <addDependencies>false</addDependencies>
                </classPath>
                <icon>path/to/icon.ico</icon>
                <jre>
                    <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
                    <initialHeapSize>512</initialHeapSize>
                    <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                </jre>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The [documentation of launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html) says, that the given combination of the settings `headerType=gui` and  `stayAlive=true` will **Wait for the application to close**, which is not the case.

Since I do not have a windows machine available, I cannot try out what happens when I set `headerType=console`. The documentation says that this causes the wrapper to **always wait and return the application's exit code**. However, since my application is mainly a GUI application, I wonder whether this setting has any negative side effects. At this point I start to ask myself why I would ever want the wrapped application to have another command line behavior than the jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a windows machine up and running to test this by myself.

I solved this issue by replacing this

```xml
<headerType>gui</headerType>
<stayAlive>true</stayAlive>
```

by that

```xml
<headerType>console</headerType>
```

According to the documentation `stayAlive=true` is actually implied by `headerType=console`, so I can safely remove it from the configuration.

I was not able to notice any side-effects of this to the GUI. The only annoying thing is that this opens a console which displays the console output.

So, I guess the intended solution to this is the configuration as described in the question: `headerType=gui` and `stayAlive=true`. However, this does not work. I think this is a bug in launch4j.